# How to solve "Failed assertion: line 22 pos 16: 'target != null' : is not true" in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I am implementing google map in my flutter project and I am getting this error **Failed assertion: line 22 pos 16: 'target != null': is not true** as a red error screen for 2 seconds on my mobile device, and then the map got implemented.

How to solve that ?

here is the code:

```
body: GoogleMap(
        polylines: _polyLines,
        markers: _markers,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: latLng,
          zoom: 14,
        ),
        onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

> Answer First

SO what I here do, first I get current location using the `geolocator: ^6.1.13` plugin and simply save it into one variable and until get current location show empty container and then pass the current location to the `target` value in Google map

```
class SelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _selectionScreen();
  }
}

class _selectionScreen extends State<SelectionScreen> {
  @override
  initState() {
    loading = false;
    getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }
 bool loading;
  var start_currentPostion;

  getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      double latitude = position.latitude;
      double longitude = position.longitude;
      start_currentPostion = LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      loading = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        body: loading ? GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: start_currentPostion,
            zoom: 14,
          ),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {},
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        ) : Container());
  }
}
```

> Answer Second

So in your `GoogleMapPage` You just need to add one boolean value and update this on the basis of location

```
bool getLocationLoading;
```

Add this value in your `initState()` and set it as false after that again call this boolean variable to your `getLocation()` method and set it as true

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
    getLocationLoading = false;   // set false
  }

  getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((currentLocation) {
      print(currentLocation.latitude);
      print(currentLocation.longitude);
      setState(() {
        latLng =  LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      });

      print("getLocation:$latLng");
      _onAddMarkerButtonPressed();
      getLocationLoading = true;   // set true

    });

  }
```

and then simply add your `GoogleMap` to your body part

```
body: getLocationLoading ? GoogleMap(
  polylines: _polyLines,
  markers: _markers,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
  target: latLng,
  zoom: 14,
  ),
  onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
  _controller.complete(controller);
  },
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  ), : Container());
```

Comment: @Subham Narkhede, no still getting the error page

Comment: What you are getting here `print("getLocation:$latLng");`

Comment: @sushreesomamohanty do you getting any value?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code:
**google_map.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:thehelpdesk/components/home/map_request.dart';
import 'package:thehelpdesk/widgets/appbar.dart';

import 'dart:async';

class GoogleMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleMapPageState createState() => _GoogleMapPageState();
}

class _GoogleMapPageState extends State<GoogleMapPage> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  static LatLng latLng;

  LocationData currentLocation;
  bool loading = true;

  GoogleMapsServices _googleMapsServices = GoogleMapsServices();

  final Set<Polyline> _polyLines = {};
  Set<Polyline> get polyLines => _polyLines;

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("111"),
        position: latLng,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
  }

  getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((currentLocation) {
      print(currentLocation.latitude);
      print(currentLocation.longitude);
      setState(() {
        latLng =  LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      });

      print("getLocation:$latLng");
      _onAddMarkerButtonPressed();
      loading = false;

    });

  }

  void onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    latLng = position.target;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // setState(() {
    //   getLocation();
    // });
    super.initState();
    if(this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        getLocation();
      });
    }
  }

  void sendRequest() async {
    LatLng destination = LatLng(20.2961, 85.8245);
    String route = await _googleMapsServices.getRouteCoordinates(
        latLng, destination);
    createRoute(route);
    _addMarker(destination,"Bhubaneswar");
  }

  void createRoute(String encondedPoly) {
    _polyLines.add(Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId(latLng.toString()),
        width: 4,
        points: _convertToLatLng(_decodePoly(encondedPoly)),
        color: Colors.red));
  }

  void _addMarker(LatLng location, String address) {
    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("112"),
        position: location,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: address, snippet: "go here"),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker));
  }

  List<LatLng> _convertToLatLng(List points) {
    List<LatLng> result = <LatLng>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        result.add(LatLng(points[i - 1], points[i]));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  List _decodePoly(String poly) {
    var list = poly.codeUnits;
    var lList = new List();
    int index = 0;
    int len = poly.length;
    int c = 0;
    do {
      var shift = 0;
      int result = 0;

      do {
        c = list[index] - 63;
        result |= (c & 0x1F) << (shift * 5);
        index++;
        shift++;
      } while (c >= 32);
      if (result & 1 == 1) {
        result = ~result;
      }
      var result1 = (result >> 1) * 0.00001;
      lList.add(result1);
    } while (index < len);

    for (var i = 2; i < lList.length; i++) lList[i] += lList[i - 2];

    print(lList.toString());

    return lList;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: aapBarSection('Google Map', Colors.blueAccent[700], context),
      body: GoogleMap(
        polylines: _polyLines,
        markers: _markers,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: latLng,
          zoom: 14,
        ),
        onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          sendRequest();
        },
        label: Text('Destination'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**map_request.dart**

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

const apiKey = "My API Key";

class GoogleMapsServices{
  Future<String> getRouteCoordinates(LatLng l1, LatLng l2) async{
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${l1.latitude},${l1.longitude}&destination=${l2.latitude},${l2.longitude}&key=$apiKey";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    Map values = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print("====================>>>>>>>>$values");

    return values["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];
  }
}
```